# Generate a "bouquet" of drooping/bending Cables from preset models?

Tags: modifiers, objects, particles, physics, workflow

[image: bouquet of cables]

So I have about 6 meshes of different cables (USB, audio, etc) that are all perfectly straight and flat. I want to generate a bouquet of them clumped together , with each being repeated several times but each also having a sense of gravity to them with bending and drooping, without any of them intersecting meshes. They will be going inside a glass vase and so they all need to be gathered together at one point, and then fan out, without them going inside each other as itll be obvious through the glass. I've attached a reference image of what I'm trying to achieve, as well as the cable meshes I have. I have no idea how to achieve this, any help would be appreciated!

[image: flat cable meshes]

Comment: I expect this would involve hair or geometry notes, possibly with soft body physics on a curve involved. Can’t test for the time being.

Comment: @TheLabCat do you mind explaining this process a tiny bit more so i can experiment with it?

Comment: Can’t test for the time being. I don’t know what to tell you. I’ve never done this before, so I want to try and do it myself to see what happens/what works.